# Data transformation for permutation

Tags: algorithm, transformation

I have a square matrix MxN, with elements x<sub>ij</sub>. Each of this values is used into a function of the form some_function(i,j).
That function is applied in column order. What I want to achieve is a kernel function k(i, j) that will be placed inside some_function:

```
def some_function(i, j):
   i', j' = k(i, j)
```

I will return another set (i', j') so that (i'!=i, j'!=j) and (i', j') correspond to a real value on the initial square matrix. This function applied to each of the values (i,j) wont produce any repeated pairs. The numbers produced by the kernel function (i',j') should be distributed.

My first idea was to precompute the permutations in another list and pass that values to some_function. I would like to know if there is any better way to do it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider MxN matrix as one-dimensional array of length M*N. You want to create a transformation that uniquely maps every number in range 0..MN-1 to another number in this range (and after MN steps returns to initial index).

The simplest way to achieve this goal is to make steps of size P that is mutually prime with M and N and large than M
Example:

```
indx = M * i + j  /start cell
for k = 0.. M*N - 1 do begin
  indx = (indx + P) % (M*N) //integer modulus
  i = indx / M  //integer division
  j = indx % M  //integer modulus
end // indx returns to the start value

for M=2,N=4, P=5
indx  i   j
0     0   0
5     2   1
2     1   0
7     3   1  
4     2   0
1     0   1
6     3   0
3     1   1
```

Note that both i and j changes every time.